# How do you pass values from an activity to a class in Android Studio?

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-recyclerview

I am trying to set up a delete button to delete a customer from a table. The customers are displayed in card views using a recycler view so each customer will have their own delete button. The customer information is displayed using text views. I need to pass the customer id to the delete method in order to search the table for that specific id to delete. How do I pass the data successfully?

This is what I've currently got to try and pass the data I need

```
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull MyHolder holder, final int position) {

    holder.idText.setText(String.valueOf(id.get(position)));
    holder.nameText.setText(String.valueOf(name.get(position)));
    holder.surnameText.setText(String.valueOf(surname.get(position)));
    holder.add1Text.setText(String.valueOf(add1.get(position)));
    holder.add2Text.setText(String.valueOf(add2.get(position)));
    holder.add3Text.setText(String.valueOf(add3.get(position)));
    holder.postCodeText.setText(String.valueOf(postCode.get(position)));
    holder.phoneNumberText.setText(String.valueOf(phoneNumber.get(position)));
    holder.emailText.setText(String.valueOf(email.get(position)));

    GlobalVars.id = holder.idText.getText().toString();

    holder.delete.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            db.deleteCustomer(GlobalVars.id);
        }
    });
}
```

This is my delete method:

```
public long deleteCustomer(String id)
{
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWriteableDatabase();
    ContentValues idValue = new ContentValues();
    idValue.put(CUSTOMER_ID, id);

    return db.delete(TABLE_NAME, "where Customer_ID = " + idValue, null);
}
```

When I run the app, it displays the customers and the buttons, but when I click any of the buttons I get a blank screen. And then it returns to the login screen I have.

These are the errors that show up in [LogCat](https://sites.google.com/site/androidhowto/how-to-1/save-logcat-to-a-text-file):

```
2021-05-01 12:16:26.212 18729-18729/com.example.rowlandsflooringapp E/Zygote: isWhitelistProcess - Process is Whitelisted
2021-05-01 12:16:26.212 18729-18729/com.example.rowlandsflooringapp E/Zygote: accessInfo : 1
2021-05-01 12:16:26.244 18729-18729/com.example.rowlandsflooringapp E/andsflooringap: Unknown bits set in runtime_flags: 0x8000
2021-05-01 12:16:55.186 18729-18729/com.example.rowlandsflooringapp E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.rowlandsflooringapp, PID: 18729
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.io.File android.content.Context.getDatabasePath(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getDatabaseLocked(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:445)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getReadableDatabase(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:415)
        at com.example.rowlandsflooringapp.CustomerDB.deleteCustomer(CustomerDB.java:70)
        at com.example.rowlandsflooringapp.CustomerAdapter$1.onClick(CustomerAdapter.java:73)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:7862)
        at android.widget.TextView.performClick(TextView.java:15004)
        at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:7831)
        at android.view.View.access$3600(View.java:879)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:29359)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:883)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:237)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8167)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:496)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1100)
```

Comment: implement `public boolean deleteCustomer(...)` in `CustomerDB` by using the primary key. post it to the code and update it to be a real [mcve]. then make a `DBInteractor` interface, and pass it to the adapter. in the `DBInteractor::onDeletePressed(int id)` callback, call `CustomerDB::deleteCustomer(id)`. that should be it.

Comment: sorry im pretty new to this, and the college lecturers havent been great so far, im not entirely sure what im meant to do

Comment: Can you post your database class? You should be able to implement a delete method there and not in your adapter class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After several attempts of trying and it failing, I decided to create the delete method from scratch again. This is what I ended up with and it works great.

A delete method inside the databasehelper:

```
void deleteOneRow(String row_id){
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    long result = db.delete(TABLE_NAME, "_id=?", new String[]{row_id});
    if(result == -1){
        Toast.makeText(context, "Failed to Delete.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }else{
        Toast.makeText(context, "Successfully Deleted.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
```

Calling the delete method:

```
void confirmDialog(){
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    builder.setTitle("Delete " + name + " ?");
    builder.setMessage("Are you sure you want to delete " + name + " ?");
    builder.setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
            MyDatabaseHelper myDB = new MyDatabaseHelper(UpdateActivity.this);
            myDB.deleteOneRow(id);
            finish();
        }
    });
    builder.setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {

        }
    });
    builder.create().show();
    }
}
```